# Remove numbers in tuples and enter them in new rows in csv

Tags: python, csv, data-science

so I have an ugly CSV file with one column and only 2 rows, but it has many tuples in it, that looks like:

| Column A |
| --- |
| (1, 2, 3)(4, 5, 6)(7, 8, 9) |
| (3, 2, 1)(5, 3, 6)(9, 8, 7) |

and I want to have it looks like

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 6 |
| 9 | 8 | 7 |

any suggestions?

Comment: Read the file, replace `)(` with new lines, remove opening and closing brackets and you have fixed the input file

Comment: do you need that for printing or writing to a new csv file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a [data-science](/questions/tagged/data-science) tag, why not use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) ?

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

df = (pd.read_csv("input.csv", sep="|").squeeze()
           .str.strip("()").str.split("\)\(", expand=True)
           .melt(ignore_index=False)["value"].str.split(",\s*", expand=True)
           .sort_index().set_axis(["Column A", "Column B", "Column C"], axis=1)
      )
```

Output :

```
print(df)

     Column A Column B Column C
0        1        2        3
0        4        5        6
0        7        8        9
1        3        2        1
1        5        3        6
1        9        8        7
```

Comment: **NB** : Use `df.to_csv("output.csv")` or `df.to_excel("output.xlsx")` if you need a *fresh* file.